# Script that add double quotes to every column in csv file problem

Tags: csv, unix, awk, sed, addition

i have a CSV file with 4 columns. e.g.

```
1132,John Doe,johndoe@gmail.com,3534534543

53213,John Doe,johndoe@test.com,51352363126
```

I want to add double quotes for every value so I use this script on MAC:

```
sed 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' file.csv > file2.csv
```

I receive

```
"1132","John Doe","johndoe@gmail.com","3534534543
"

"53213","John Doe","johndoe@test.com","51352363126
"
```

So I get the last quotes on new rows, most probably I should remove /r/n somehow, I tried but I couldn`t. Any ideas? It happens with the files that I receive if I fill values manually it works as expected.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/,/","/g; s/\(.*\)\r/"\1"/' file`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment97778025_45772525

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C file` or `xxd file` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";RS="\r\n";s1="\"";OFS="\",\""} {$1=$1;$0=s1 $0 s1} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to leave empty lines then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";RS="\r\n";s1="\"";OFS="\",\""} NF{$1=$1;$0=s1 $0 s1} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks but same case. I guess its related with that its on Mac. I will try it on Windows or Linux..

Comment: I suggest to add `RS="\r\n"; FS=",";` in `BEGIN` section.

Comment: Sorry but where exactly?

Comment: @NikolayRumenov, as per Cyrus sir suggestion I have added them now.

Comment: I pasted the result below

Comment: @NikolayRumenov, Could you please do lemme know if you have tried my 2nd solution `awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";RS="\r\n";s1="\"";OFS="\",\""} NF{$1=$1;$0=s1 $0 s1} 1' Input_file` this should work IMHO, lemme know please.

Comment: @Cyrus - any such suggestion that would fix an `awk` solution should, likely, fix the OP's original `sed` solution too. Which would be a much better approach; `awk` is great, but it's not fast - compared to `sed`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i tested it. Same case. I tested all solutions on Windows and they work very well. Thank you all

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you how to remove the quotes of the first string after the file is done.. New requirement...

Comment: @NikolayRumenov, np, you could try like, `awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";RS="\r\n";s1="\"";OFS="\",\""} NF{$1=$1;$0=$0} 1' Input_file` and lemme know how it goes.

Comment: 12","John Doe","doe@gmail.com","324234

Comment: It removes the first one and last one( the last value). so close

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, it is possible that the file you received has different control characters at the end of the line.

One easy fix is to exclude control characters, as well as comma, from matching. That is, instead of searching for `[^,]*`, you can search for `[^,[:cntrl:]]*`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a proper CSV parser on CSV data. [Ruby ships with one](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), so you can write

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
    csv_in  = CSV.new(STDIN)
    csv_out = CSV.new(STDOUT, force_quotes: true)
    csv_in.each {|row| csv_out << row}
' < file.csv
```